# Is there a way to toggle between Lightning and Classic Community

Tags: lightning, profile, customer-community, permission-sets, user-registration

Here is my use case. I have one community that works in 'lightning' (Customer Service Template) and the other that works in classic (Salesforce tabs + visualforce). The users can be common.

1. Is there a way they can toggle from Classic to Lightning community and from 
     Lightning Community to Classic Community?
2. Also, each community has different tabs that appear based on the profile 
     and permission sets. I am trying to figure out how the self-registration 
     would work too. Once they sign up, what profile they will be assigned in 
     order to access the both communities and their tabs accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way they can toggle between those two communities?

**Yes**.

For Lightning Communities, you can use [App Launcher](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_enable_app_launcher.htm&type=0) to let users toggle between Communities they are member of.

> Display the App Launcher in Lightning communities to make it easy for members to move between their communities and their Salesforce org.

For Salesforce Tabs + VF page communities, you can [Enable the Global Header for Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_global_header.htm&type=5).

> In Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce communities and Salesforce Classic, the global header lets you switch between your communities and your Salesforce org.

---

> 2. Also, each community has different tabs that appear based on the profile and permission sets. I am trying to figure out how the self-registration would work too. Once they sign up, what profile they will be assigned in order to access the both communities and their tabs accordingly?

Community Users are associated to an Account. Once Users register themselves, they are associated with a Contact associated to that Account. During registration you determine which profile they should be assigned to. This profile should have the necessary access required for the User to be able to view different objects, tabs. All these permissions will be applicable for the Users on all those communities wherever these objects, tabs are available and they have access to.

As to how you can provide Users access to a Community or multiple Communities, you will need to add the Profile/Permission Set as Members in the Community. Only when you add the profile as member, Users get access to a particular community.

Here are few links which will provide you with more details around these topics:

- [Enable the App Launcher in Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_enable_app_launcher.htm&type=0)
- [Enable the Global Header for Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_global_header.htm&type=5)
- [Create Communities Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_create_external_users.htm&type=0)
- [Add Members to Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_members.htm&type=0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. well my question is can I toggle from Lighting community to Classic community and classic community to lightning community? I have edited the question as well in case if it was not clear.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect that ask.